# a formal definition of self-conjugacy

Tags: definition

C(n) := number of integer partitions of number

```
For instance: 43 = 7 + 5 + 5 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1

 -------------------------------------------------
 Integer Partition of 43 with 13 parts
```

we can use this to make  a **picture**(  Ferrers diagrams).

Symmetry about the down-to-the-right diagonal makes the partition self-conjugate.

**Question**:  Write a formal definition of self-conjugacy that refers only to the
parts $c_1, c_2, c_3$, ... and without referring to a picture(  Ferrers diagrams).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=c_1+c_2+\ldots+c_m$ be a partition written in non-increasing order. For $k=1,\ldots,c_1$ let

$$d_k=|\{\ell\in[m]:c_\ell\ge k\}|\;;$$

then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{c_1}d_k&=\sum_{k=1}^{c_1}|\{\ell\in[m]:c_\ell\ge k\}|\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{c_1}\sum_{\ell=1}^m[c_\ell\ge k]\\
&=\sum_{\ell=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^{c_1}[c_\ell\ge k]\\
&=\sum_{\ell=1}^mc_\ell\\
&=n\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $[c_\ell\ge k]$ is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Moreover it’s clear that $d_1\ge d_2\ge\ldots\ge d_{c_1}$, so $n=d_1+d_2+\ldots+d_{c_1}$ is a partition of $n$ written in non-increasing order, and in fact it is the partition conjugate to the original partition. Thus, the original partition is self conjugate if and only if $c_1=m$, and

$$c_k=d_k=|\{\ell\in[m]:c_\ell\ge k\}|$$

for $k=1,\ldots,m$.

Comment: this is great answer! thanks Prof. Brian for your lucids answers!!! It is such a pleasure to read your solutions.